# Use enum values as a Tag in JUnit 5

Tags: junit, enums, tags, junit5, junit-jupiter

I like the new [`@Tag`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Tag.html) feature in JUnit 5 as [shown in the manual](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering).

I have one concern. The tag values are mere strings. That means typos might happen.

➥ Is there some way to get the tag behavior but using values from an enum(s) that I define?

Or some other way I can depend on the compiler to enforce valid values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Meta Annotations

Use [Java annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) rather than [Java enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

You can define your own annotation to wrap a JUnit `@Tag` annotation. So you need write the string of your tag value only once, then apply that custom annotation throughout your suites of tests.

The meta-annotations are checked by the compiler to ensure valid values, as you asked for in your Question.

See the [manual on Meta-Annotations](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations). And see [this slide](https://youtu.be/0qI6_NKFQsY?t=952) in a YouTube video of a talk by [Marc Philipp](https://www.marcphilipp.de/en/about-me/).

### Example

Declare [your own annotation type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html).

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE , ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
@Tag( "fast" )
@Test
public @interface FastTest {}
```

Later, when you write your tests, annotate with your new `@FastTest` annotation.

Instead of writing this:

```
@Tag( "fast" ) 
@Test
void someTest() { … }
```

…write this:

```
@FastTest
void someTest() { … }
```